# react-native link is not linking my custom fonts

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native, I was link my custom fonts.
This is my pakage.json

```
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
   "./assets/fonts/"
    ]
  }
```

When i fired this command

```
react-native link
```

Its is linking the Fontawesome fonts but not the custom fonts.
Please help me with the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thie might help [Ultimate guide to use custom fonts in react native](https://medium.com/@mehrankhandev/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4)

Comment: I have this the same procedure in the link provided. But still its not link my custom fonts